# How to set a connectionstring value in app.config file?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

My sample app.config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBconn" connectionString="driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};server=10.78.17.229;database=grocery;uid=root;pwd=admin;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I want to set connectionstring value from the c# code.
I am not able to change the file content. Please help me.

Comment: You normally only have write permissions when you run the whole app as Admin, not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

**App.cofig** Code

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <configuration>
     <configSections>
            <section name="dataConfiguration"type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,        PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
     </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DbDatabase" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString=""/>
</connectionStrings>
```

C# Code

```
   public void updateConfigFile(string con)
    {
        //updating config file
        XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        //Loading the Config file
        XmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
       // XmlDoc.Load("App.config");
        foreach (XmlElement xElement in XmlDoc.DocumentElement)
        {
            if (xElement.Name == "connectionStrings")
            {
                //setting the coonection string
                xElement.FirstChild.Attributes[2].Value = con;
            }
        }
        //writing the connection string in config file
        XmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
        //XmlDoc.Save("App.config");
    }



 private void btn_Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder Con = new StringBuilder("Data Source=");
        Con.Append(txt_ServerName.Text);
        Con.Append(";Initial Catalog=");
        Con.Append(txt_DatabaseName.Text);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_UserId.Text) &&String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_Password.Text))
            Con.Append(";Integrated Security=true;");
        else
        {
            Con.Append(";User Id=");
            Con.Append(txt_UserId.Text);
            Con.Append(";Password=");
            Con.Append(txt_Password.Text);
        }
        string strCon = Con.ToString();
        updateConfigFile(strCon);

        DatabaseTableDA da = new DatabaseTableDA();
        tableList = da.Select_Tables();
        this.lstTables.DataSource = tableList;
    }
```

Comment: Please add descriptive commentation in detail in your answer on how your answer differs from the previous answer. (given the comment on the previous answer by the OP appears to solve it)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure this is the approach you should be taking but anyway this might work for you?

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ConfigurationSectionCollection sections = config.Sections;

foreach (ConfigurationSection section in sections)
{
    ConnectionStringsSection connSettings = section as ConnectionStringsSection;

    if (connSettings != null)
    {
        connSettings.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString = "....";
    }
}
```